# Как использовать static ссылки в css (Django)?

Tags: css, django

Доброго времени суток!

Приступила к изучению Django (делаю тестовое приложение-каталог для фильмов), и столкнулась со следующим вопросом: как использовать static ссылки в css файле (Django)?

Смотрите, есть следующая структура папки static:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

LK_library - это папка проекта; в css - один единственный файл styles.css, а в папках fonts и images, соответственно, файлы шрифтов и изображений.

Вот таким образом выглядит подключение шрифтов:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Kyiv Type";
src:
  url("resources/kyivtypetitling/KyivTypeTitling-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
  url("resources/kyivtypetitling/KyivTypeTitling.woff") format("woff");
```

}

И фонового изображения:

```
background-image: url("resources/hero_bg.png");
```

Естественно, все это до танцев с бубном (начало работы с Django).

Первым делом, я пошла менять путь подключения шрифтов и изображения (по примеру того, как я делала это в самом файле html, который и использует файл styles.css):

```
{% load static %}

@font-face {
font-family: "Kyiv Type";
src:
  url("{% static 'fonts/KyivTypeTitling-Regular.woff' %} ") format("woff"),
  url("{% static 'fonts/KyivTypeTitling.woff' %} ") format("woff");}

background-image: url("{% static 'images/hero_bg.png' %}");
```

Результата не было никакого. После я убрала "url" из маршрутов:

```
{% load static %}

@font-face {
font-family: "Kyiv Type";
src:
  "{% static 'fonts/KyivTypeTitling-Regular.woff' %} " format("woff"),
  "{% static 'fonts/KyivTypeTitling.woff' %} " format("woff");
}

background-image: "{% static 'images/hero_bg.png' %}";
```

И снова ничего. Естественно, в первую очередь я пошла смотреть в лог, и получила следующий ответ от системы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Казалось бы, чего проще - файлы по следующим адресам не найдены. Только загвоздка в том, что папки "resources" и папки "kyivtypetitling" просто нет в проекте, и ссылок на эти папки тоже нигде нет.

Вернее как: ранее в процессе верстки я действительно создавала данные папки, только в процессе создания самого проекта Django шрифты из папки kyivtypetitling были перенесены в папку static/fonts, а изображения из папки "resources" были перенесены в папку static/images.

При чем сам .css явно подключен корректно, поскольку все элементы на странице выровнены правильно.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я могла ошибиться (ну новичок я в Django).

Comment: Используйте ссылку формата `static/fonts/KyivTypeTitling-Regular.woff`, то есть пропишите точный путь от папки static до конечного файла. Нет смысла в css использовать шаблонизатор

Comment: @Medvedev, в принципе, тоже вполне реальный вариант - уже проверила. Просто я почему-то была уверенна, что если в html файлы можно вставить шаблонизаторы, то и в css можно вставить их же.

Comment: Вообще использовать можно, но смысла особо в этом нет, стили динамически не меняются, а значит не рационально задействовать шаблонизатор. Если посмотрите в консоль, то увидите, что в css работает, только почему у вас не те папки подгружаются, уже другой вопрос, возможно ошибка в settings или urls, попробуйте скопировать названия папок из консоли, которые вылезли как 404, и поискать по названию в настройках. Может получится понять почему так.

Comment: @Medvedev, проблема решилась довольно тривиальным способом - перезапуском тестового сервера - после этого обновились адреса файлов. Спасибо за пояснение на счет шаблонизаторов в статических файлах!

Answer (score 0):

Не работает конкретно что? Если не применяются стили и остальное при условии что

```
DEBUG = True
```

то попробуйте добавить следующий код в настройки вашего проекта

```
# settings.py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

и файл URLConf

```
# urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: прочитал ваш вопрос, и увидел в чём крылась проблема. Прошу прощения за невнимательность. Тогда подключите ваши файлы с шрифтами напрямую, как указано в комментариях выше

Comment: я пока что так и сделала. Как я поняла, использовать шаблонизаторы в css просто нереально?

Comment: да, просто нереально. Такого к сожалению нету